# In docker, how to change shared folder on running state

Tags: docker

I run my docker container with command blow.

```
docker run -v /host/folder:/docker/container/folder my_image
```

If I want to change shared folder, should I restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been requested many times, and it is currently not possible. Containers should be ephemeral. You should be able to restart the container again without lose of data.

Check the following [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31452) for more reasons why this is not possible.